# Javascript function firing on page load, not on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

The function "display()" is firing on page load instead of on click. I'm not sure why. When I change the function to "alert" it shows the issue more visibly. I thought to try changing the parameter variable, but it didn't work. I used x and content. How do I get it to stop firing on load? It's also only loading the first two divs. I used the same format on a separate javascript page and it worked fine.

I don't

https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/92r0apd9/
JS:

```
var firstTrimesterButton = document.getElementById('firstTri');
var secondTrimesterButton = document.getElementById('secTri');
var thirdTrimesterButton = document.getElementById('thirdTri');
var firstThreeMonthsButton = document.getElementById('firstThreeMonths');
var secondThreeMonthsButton = document.getElementById('secThreeMonths');
var thirdThreeMonthsButton = document.getElementById('thirdThreeMonths');
var fourthThreeMonthsButton = document.getElementById('fourthThreeMonths');
var toddlersButton = document.getElementById('toddlers');

var fTContent = document.getElementById('fTContent');
var sTContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');
var tTContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');
var firstTMContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');
var sTMContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');
var tTMContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');
var fourthTMContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');
var toddlersContent = document.getElementById('sTContent');

//event listeners
firstTrimesterButton.addEventListener("click", display(fTContent));
secondTrimesterButton.addEventListener("click",display(sTContent));
thirdTrimesterButton.addEventListener("click", display(tTContent));
firstThreeMonthsButton.addEventListener("click", display(firstTMContent) );
secondThreeMonthsButton.addEventListener("click", display(sTMContent));
thirdThreeMonthsButton.addEventListener("click", display(tTMContent));
fourthThreeMonthsButton.addEventListener("click",display(fourthTMContent));
toddlersButton.addEventListener("click",display(toddlersContent));

//function
function display(content) {
    content.style.display= 'inline';
}
```

Comment: One more problem is: your code has a lot of copy-paste. I recommend you set special class for every clickable element and data-param for elements to display, and attach your event-listener for these elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put reference to callback function into your `addEventListener`. If you set `display(fTContent)` - you just run this function.
The right triggering is

```
firstTrimesterButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    display(fTContent);
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation regarding what is the problem and how this code solve it. The current answer is very low quality.

Comment: While this is correct, you provide no explanation what-so-ever, or any attempt of such.

Comment: I understood this to mean that I wasn't using the right trigger syntax. It fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `addEventListener` needs to be a function.

Since you are invoking `display()` and not passing it as reference you can make that named function return a function that will only be called when the event occurs

You can change:

```
function display(content) {
    content.style.display= 'inline';
}
```

To

```
function display(content) {    
    return function(){
       content.style.display= 'inline';
    }       
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/92r0apd9/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: @StephanBijzitter an explanation is provided